# Using exec and fileevent to maintain subprocess

Tags: tcl, exec

I have a work for TCL script.
In the main script, I can invoke a new script by using exec to do it

```
set AAA [exec tclsh "scriptA.tcl"]
```

and I can terminate the subprocess by press enter to kill the process.

```
fileevent stdin readable killproc 
vwait state
```

Now I want to do let it kill the correspond process automatically if my
subprocess working functionally to finished and keep the press enter kill proc 
work, how can I implement by not using `open` or `bgexec`, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the first one:

```
set AAA [exec tclsh "scriptA.tcl"]
```

The Tcl program (or at least the current thread in that program) in which you've put that statement does not proceed until the subprocess has completed. Tcl stops and waits for it.

The other alternative (that doesn't use `open` or `bgexec`) is to put a `&` as the last argument:

```
set AAA [exec tclsh "scriptA.tcl" &]
```

However, in this case the subprocess is started in the background and there's no real connection to the master process, which continues immediately. The `AAA` variable in this case wouldn't contain the output from the program, but rather the process ID of the subprocess; you can use that ID with your platform's usual system tools to monitor it. (Many unixes let you look at `/proc/$processID` to find out information about running processes. Not all though; it isn't standardised, and the contents of that directory *really* isn't standardised. You could also look at what tools the TclX package provides; several of them can use a process ID, provided you know how to use the POSIX system calls that it wraps.)

In Tcl 8.6, we added other options for monitoring and handling a subprocess: you can make a genuine OS-understood unidirectional raw unnamed pipe with `chan pipe` (it's hooked up to a pair of channels), and can close just one end of a bidirectional channel using an extra argument to `close`. This lets you do things like using a `fileevent` to monitor a subprocess even if you made it with `exec`, but it's not really much simpler at that point than using `open`. The `exec` command supports connecting channels directly to subprocesses, but currently only for channels that have real OS handles associated with them (pipes, yes; sockets, yes; terminals, yes; files, yes; elaborate script-driven channels made with `chan create`, no).

---

In general, we recommend that you keep things simple:

- `exec …` for when you want to run a subprocess and wait immediately for the result.
- `open |[list …]` for when you want to run a subprocess in the background and interact with it (or `bgexec`, which provides a slightly different interface to the same functionality). Remember that Tcl's `fileevent` *works* with pipelines and terminals as well as sockets.
- `exec … &` for when you want to run a subprocess in the background and completely relinquish control over it.

And in the *really* complicated cases, there's the Expect package.